# How to combine nested model lambdas in razor syntax

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

My View Model

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

In my razor view I am trying to get data for my comment

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Post"))
{


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Comments.Data);
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comments.Data, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Comments.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Comment </button>
}
```

But I am getting errors

then I tried the following syntax

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Post"))
{

    @foreach(var comment in Model.Comments)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(comment.Data);
            @Html.TextAreaFor(comment.Data, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(comment.Id)
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Comment </button>

    }
}
```

But I am still getting errors

actually I am doing a blog project

So, I am hoping to have Post, all old comment and new comment button in a Details page

Comment: what is the error and on which line specifically ?

Comment: m.Comments.Data and m.Comments.Id can't detect these in lambda expression

Comment: your lambda syntax is wrong, see posted answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehsan Sajjad Made me understand that we can write lambda expression like this

```
@Html.LabelFor(x=> comment.Data)
```

later I solved my problem, actually my approach was quite wrong

for solving my problem I add another component NewComment in my ViewModel

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public Comment NewComment { get; set; } // this is new addition
}
```

Then My New Comment area is like the following in the razor syntax

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Post", Model.Post))
{


    var comment = Model.NewComment;

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => comment.Data);
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => comment.Data, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => comment.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Comment </button>
}
```

I am doing a project where in Details view

Firstly, Appeared a Post

Secondly, It's comment

Thirdly, A section for it's new comment

Full code for it's details page

```
@model SimpleBlog.Models.PostViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@*Post Section*@

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1> @Model.Post.Title </h1>
    <p class="lead"> @Model.Post.PostedBy </p>
    <p> @Model.Post.PostDate.ToString("d MMM yyyy") </p>

</div>

<br />

<div class="jumbotron">

    <p class="lead"> @Model.Post.Body </p>

</div>


@* Old comments section *@

@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{

    <h4>  @comment.CommentBy  </h4>
    <h4>  @comment.CommentDate.ToString("d MMM yyyy") </h4>
    <h4> @comment.Data  </h4>

    <br />
    <br />

}

@* New Comment section *@

@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Post", Model.Post))
{


    var comment = Model.NewComment;

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => comment.Data);
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => comment.Data, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => comment.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Comment </button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda syntax is wrong. The following will compile and work but the values won't be posted back to the controller action:

```
@foreach(var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x=> comment.Data)
}
```

Secondly, for posting collection back to action it should be done in a for loop with index named controls as the model binder binds it back to collection using the names of the input control that will not be generated in the format which model binder needs.

Do like:

```
@for(int i=0; i < Model.Comments.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Comments[i].Data);
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => Model.Comments[i].Data, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Comments[i].Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Comment </button>

}
```

Comment: your for loop solution is not working, your this suggestion is working **@Html.LabelFor(x=> comment.Data)**

Comment: still don't recognize this **Model.Comments[i].Data**. I solved the problem 

I will post the answer later

Comment: @SHAHMDIMRANHOSSAIN my bad. you will need to make it `List` or convert it to `List` but from your post it seems you did something else